# Power BI Dataset(or few columns) into Power Apps

Tags: powerbi, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I want to access a Power BI dataset (or few columns of it) in Power App.

Whenever I'm trying to add `Data Connection` -> `Select PowerBI (Preview)` -> Type in my `PowerBI` credentials, then under Data, `PowerBI` is visible, but I cannot select it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do more than this using the connector. [Read more](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Discussion/Cannot-use-PowerBI-as-data-source/td-p/89247)

After adding connector, you can go ahead and add a PowerBI tile from controls in a screen. Then choose a **Workspace - Dashboard - Tile**.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @shankar If my answer was helpful, can you upvote/mark it as answer to help others find it useful.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful.Really it is helpful to other power BI users.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Power BI connector (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/powerbi/#actions) and one of the following actions:

- Run a json query against a dataset
- Run a query against a dataset

You may need to call these via a Power Automate flow to translate the response properly.